Kafka - как реализовать дедубликацию при падении приложения?
Есть приложение, читает файл построчно и передаёт в Kafka. При падении приложения и затем восстановлении, необходимо продолжить или заново начать отправку в Kafka, но чтобы не дублировать ранее отправленные строки. Kafka даёт какие либо инструменты для решения этой проблемы? идемпотентность и exactly one это то, что мне нужно?

У Кафки есть транзакции https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Этот вариант я смотрел. Он не обеспечивает решение. Kafka поддерживает распределённые транзакции с полноценными ACID-гарантиями только в пределах самой себя

Вполне обеспечивает - открыл транзакцию, пишешь строки файла в Кафку, закрыл транзакцию. Пока транзакция открыта, консьюмеры не видят незакомиченные сообщения. Если продюсер упал, то при рестарте просто начинаешь писать с начала.

"консьюмеры не видят незакомиченные сообщения" - но их тоже надо переводить в транзакционный режим.

нет случайно описания такой архитектуры на примере ?

Есть, ссылка в первом комментарии

Для продюсера важно выставить transaction.timeout.ms и transactional.id, для консюмера - isolation.level, остальное по вкусу
